# runnable future interface definition (jdk)

Tags: java, interface, runnable, future

I have a question about the "correctness" of the RunnableFuture interface's definition.  This may be a question about the correct contention for defining interfaces comments in java.

The definition of the RunnableFuture's run() method:

> Sets this Future to the result of its computation ...

However, this clearly cannot be always true, since run()'s return type is `void`, and RunnableFuture is but an interface, it seems that if we were to gaurantee this, we would have to know something about the nature of the implementing class (the get() implementation, for example).

Now, if the RunnableFuture actually returned a value, which was hidden and always returned by an otherwise blocking get() function, such a definition (which would have to occur in a class, rather than an interface, due to its implementation restriction), would clearly be appropriate.

Thus, I am wondering: is the run() method for this interface correctly defined ?

As a counterexample: the Runnable run() interface definition is always correct.

> When an object implementing interface Runnable is used to create a
>   thread, starting the  thread causes the object's run method to be
>   called in that separately executing thread.

Thus, even though Runnable defines no implementation - the interface tells us how the JVM implements threads via the Runnable interface, without unnecessarily imposing non-gauranteed contract on implementing classes.

So I have 3 questions:

1. Is the documentation for RunnableFuture capable of being incorrect for several cases  ?
2. If (1) is the case, is that acceptable via java conventions?
3. What is the "real" difference between a RunnableFuture run() and a Runnable run(), if any ?

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

The contract of `RunnableFuture` is implemented by [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html). When you create a `FutureTask`, you provide either a `Callable` or a `Runnable` and a value. The `run` method of `FutureTask` looks something like:

```
public void run() {
    V result;
    try {
        if(callable) {
            result = callable.call();
        } else {
            runnable.run();
            result = value;
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        setException(t);
        return;
    }
    set(result);
}
```

Except the actual implementation wraps the `Runnable`-value pair in a `Callable` and does some extra checks to ensure the `FutureTask` is in the correct state before `run` is invoked.

Comment: Hmmm... so maybe you are suggesting that, normally, we dont implement our own futures, but rather, in idiomatic "future" programming , we should simply use the FutureTask. I could see that as being the case.  But if this is so, I'm wondering wether its wise for the RunnableFuture to be custom extensible at all in the JDK.  Let me know if I'm misinterpreting your answer --- Im not sure what the thrust of your point is.  Thanks.

Comment: @jayunit100 I was just trying to clarify how `RunnableFuture` was meant to be implemented since you seemed to be confused about it. You are correct, you will almost never need to implement your own `Future` from scratch, you can just use `FutureTask` as a base and build off of it if you have to. The way the JDK is set up currently, there's no reason `RunnableFuture` could not itself be a concrete class (replacing `FutureTask`). However, I suppose the designers wanted the use of `RunnableFuture` to be as flexible as possible.